# Using Data Source=. , Wherethe database will be stored?

Tags: c#, connection-string

In a program  I found the following connection string and can't figure out where will the database? What kind of server will be used? What will be it's Name/Server/Network Address?

My first thought was "will it work?" but it does as the application is running  and has data.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="FooBarDB_ConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=FOOBAR_TEST;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I was looking at [connection-string-syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax) but didn't catch Something related to that single  dot `.` as Data source value

Comment: the dot means localhost, default instance. It won't work if the database server is on another machine.

Comment: Is your program changing connection string from elsewhere in the code, and not using it as it is from configuration?

Comment: @Crowcoder, I knew about local and local Db but first time I saw a simple dot. And loocking for it on Googl didn't gave result. Let's clause this as a dupe and hope it doesn't get deleted. I had to go to 3rd page on google search. And no one goes to 3rd page.